# Looping through column names and finding them in values of 1 column in another dataset in r

Tags: r, loops

I have 2 datasets:  first is "se_target":

| variable_name | group | var&scale | value | min_scale | max_scale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| glob01 | new | glob01_greater_equal3_lower4 | 0.02 | 3 | 4 |
| glob01 | new | glob01_greater_equal5_lowerInf | 0.06 | 5 | 5 |
| glob02 | new | glob02_greater_equal1_lower3 | 0.07 | 1 | 3 |
| glob03 | old | glob03_greater_equal3_lowerInf | 0.1 | 3 | 5 |

and second "se" with surgery results with scales 1-5

| hhkey | glob01 | glob02 | glob03 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 | 4 | 3 |

Note that in second dataset there is much more columns with yglob beggining, as they are survey questions. I want to write a loop that will create new dataset by checking every value of every column in "se" dataset starting with "glob" character and for this column name and value finds colname in "variable_name" column in "se_target" dataset and checks the value if its between values of min_scale and max_scale in order to find a row.

The output should look like this:

| hhkey | group | var&scale | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | new | glob01_greater_equal3_lower4 | 0.02 |
| 1 | new | glob02_greater_equal1_lower3 | 0.07 |
| 1 | old | glob03_greater_equal1_lower3 | 0.1 |
| 2 | new | glob01_greater_equal5_lowerInf | 0.06 |

I tried to do it with this code:

```
output_df <- data.frame()

# loop through each column in dataset2 that starts with 'yglob'
for (col_name in grep("^glob", names(se), value = TRUE)) {
  
  # get the column index of the current column
  col_index <- which(names(se) == col_name)
  
  # join the two datasets based on the variable_name and yglob column name
  joined_df <- se_target %>% 
    inner_join(
      se %>% 
        select(hhkey, group, !!col_name),
      by = c("variable_name" = col_name)
    )
  
  # create a new column in joined_df with target group based on the value of the yglob column
  joined_df <- joined_df %>% 
    mutate(target_group_new = case_when(
      .data[[col_name]] >= se_target$min_scale[col_index] & .data[[col_name]] <= se_target$max_scale[col_index] ~ se_target$target_group[col_index],
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
    ))
  
  # select the columns to be included in the output
  output_cols <- c("hhkey", "variable_name", "group, "var&scale", "target_group_new", "recruitment_power")
  
  # filter the joined_df to keep only the rows where the target group is not NA
  filtered_df <- joined_df %>% 
    filter(!is.na(target_group_new)) %>% 
    select(output_cols)
  
  # add the filtered_df to the output data frame
  output_df <- bind_rows(output_df, filtered_df)
}

# arrange the output data frame by hhkey and variable_name
output_df <- output_df %>% 
  arrange(hhkey, variable_name)
```

but got an error.

Comment: Why isn't the row for hhkey 2 and glob3 included? The value is 3 and that is between 3 and 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems somewhat straighforward using `tidy` and `dplyr`. For example

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
se %>% 
  pivot_longer(-1, values_to = "match_val") %>% 
  inner_join(se_target, join_by(name==variable_name, between(match_val, min_scale, max_scale)))
#   hhkey name   match_val group var.scale                      value min_scale max_scale
#   <int> <chr>      <int> <chr> <chr>                          <dbl>     <int>     <int>
# 1     1 glob01         4 new   glob01_greater_equal3_lower4    0.02         3         4
# 2     1 glob02         3 new   glob02_greater_equal1_lower3    0.07         1         3
# 3     1 glob03         4 old   glob03_greater_equal3_lowerInf  0.1          3         5
# 4     2 glob01         5 new   glob01_greater_equal5_lowerInf  0.06         5         5
# 5     2 glob03         3 old   glob03_greater_equal3_lowerInf  0.1          3         5
```

tested with

```
se <- structure(list(hhkey = 1:2, glob01 = 4:5, glob02 = 3:4, glob03 = 4:3), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
se_target <- structure(list(variable_name = c("glob01", "glob01", "glob02", 
"glob03"), group = c("new", "new", "new", "old"), var.scale = c("glob01_greater_equal3_lower4", 
"glob01_greater_equal5_lowerInf", "glob02_greater_equal1_lower3", 
"glob03_greater_equal3_lowerInf"), value = c(0.02, 0.06, 0.07, 
0.1), min_scale = c(3L, 5L, 1L, 3L), max_scale = c(4L, 5L, 3L, 
5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```